# Jest Test On TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, jestjs, test-coverage

I have a react application that uses Jest and jest-teamcity-reporter as a testResultsProcessor
[image]

my npm test scripts is as follow :
[image]

the problem is when i run my build in team city which contains test coverage, the test is running but i cannot see the test tab in the result and also the number of test passed.
[image]
in the logs i have the following errors :
[image]

Please note that i have other projects with the same template and i don't have a problem seeing the test tab and the metrics
[image]

finally here is my build steps defined in the template
[image]

Could you please help me with this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the test result processor in your jest configuration object inside your package.json.

`"testResultsProcessor": "jest-teamcity-reporter"`

To test locally, you need to set a variable in command line : `SET TEAMCITY_VERSION=1`

You will see logs lines starting with `##teamcity` and that's the metrics you're looking for.

Comment: I can see the log lined in Build Log, however, number of test passed or coverage is not reflected to build views/tabs.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: @Hasan, I had the same issue, the problem was that jest was configured in the package.json and jest.config.json, after I moved everything to jest.config.json, it worked.